# error: no matching function for call to ‘QGenericMatrix<4, 3, float>::QGenericMatrix(const float&, const float&, ..., float)’

Tags: c++, qt

I'm constructing a matrix like below:

```
QMatrix4x3 floatPos4x3 = QMatrix4x3( floatPos0.at(0), floatPos1.at(0), floatPos2.at(0),
                                     floatPos0.at(1), floatPos1.at(1), floatPos2.at(1),
                                     floatPos0.at(2), floatPos1.at(2), floatPos2.at(2),
                                     float(1)       , float(1)       , float(1)        );
```

But I'm getting the error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘QGenericMatrix<4, 3, float>::QGenericMatrix(const float&, const float&, const float&, const float&, const float&, const float&, const float&, const float&, const float&, float, float, float)’

I just simply intend to have constant float values of `1.0` inside the last row of my matrix, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QMatrix4x3` is a typedef for `QGenericMatrix<4, 3, float>`. The constructor of *QGenericMatrix* expects the values as an array, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgenericmatrix.html#QGenericMatrix-2).

Thus, my solution would be the following:

```
float values[] = {
    floatPos0.at(0), floatPos1.at(0), floatPos2.at(0),
    floatPos0.at(1), floatPos1.at(1), floatPos2.at(1),
    floatPos0.at(2), floatPos1.at(2), floatPos2.at(2),
    float(1)       , float(1)       , float(1)
};

QMatrix4x3 floatPos4x3(values);
```

Comment: Another quick question: do you know if it is possible to multiply two matrices which are of type `QGenericMatrix`? As far as I tested, the `M1 * M2` is not working.

Comment: @user3405291 What about [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgenericmatrix.html#operator-2a)?

Comment: `NNxM2` and `M1xNN` get me confused. I don't understand yet how to use them.

Comment: @user3405291, please ask another question and add the code for the two matrices you want to multiply. I will take a look at it and answer if I can.

Comment: I somehow converted all my `QGenericMatrix` matrices into `QMatrix4x4` and now I'm able to do the matrix product. It is just a temporary workaround. I will a question. Thanks.

Comment: I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52032848/3405291) and added the code I tried for the two matrices I want to multiply. Thanks!