# error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘QGenericMatrix<4, 4, float>’ and ‘QGenericMatrix<4, 3, float>’)

Tags: c++, qt, qgenericmatrix

I'm trying to multiply two matrices like this:

```
float values4x3[] = {
    3, 3, 3,
    1, 1, 1,
    2, 2, 2,
    1, 1, 1
};
QGenericMatrix< 4, 3, float > myMat4x3 (values4x3);

float values4x4[] = {
    3, 3, 3, 3,
    1, 1, 1, 1,
    2, 2, 2, 2,
    1, 1, 1, 1
};
QGenericMatrix< 4, 4, float > myMat4x4 (values4x4);

QGenericMatrix< 4, 3, float > product4x3 = myMat4x4 * myMat4x3;

qDebug() << __func__ << "product4x3 = " << product4x3;
```

However, I'm receiving the error:

> error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘QGenericMatrix<4, 4, float>’ and ‘QGenericMatrix<4, 3, float>’)

---

There is [this operator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgenericmatrix.html#operator-2a) for multiplying two instances of `QGenericMatrix`, but I'm confused and not sure how to use it with its `NNxM2` and `M1xNN`.

---

### UPDATE

As suggested by @scopchanov I swapped the two matrices like this:

```
QGenericMatrix< 4, 3, float > product4x3 = myMat4x3 * myMat4x4;
```

Now, the error is resolved and the result is logged like this:

```
qDebug() << __func__ << "product4x3 = " << product4x3;
```

Logs:

```
product4x3 =  QGenericMatrix<4, 3, float>(
    19        19        19        19         
    10        10        10        10         
    10        10        10        10         
)
```

The resulted matrix above is actually `3x4`! Well, it is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Annyo has made a very good point. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cause

In mathematics the multiplication order should be `MxP` times `PxN` to produce `MxN` product. In other words the inner dimensions of the matrices must agree.

However, the documentation for [`QGenericMatrix<M1, M2, TT> operator*`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgenericmatrix.html#operator-2a) states:

> Returns the product of the NNxM2 matrix m1 and the M1xNN matrix m2 to produce a M1xM2 matrix result.

This means, that in order to get the result of the multiplication of `A` and `B`, one should write first `B` and then `A`.

To be honest, I find this rather bizzare, considering what we are used to.

## Solution

Swap the places of the matrices like this:

```
QGenericMatrix< 4, 3, float > product4x3 = myMat4x3 * myMat4x4;
```

## Result

For the example given by you the result is:

```
MainWindow product4x3 =  QGenericMatrix<4, 3, float>(
        19        19        19        19         
        10        10        10        10         
        10        10        10        10         
)
```

Comment: Thanks, swapping matrices worked! But it is still confusing :)

Comment: @user3405291, I have update my answer to make it more comprehensive about that confusion.

Comment: @scopchanov I think there is still a mistake : swapping the matrices will allow the code to compile, but you also changed the operation @user3405291 intended to do, the result should be `[ [21 21 21] [7 7 7] [14 14 14] [7 7 7] ]`. I think there is another confusion : we are used to describe matrices with `rows*columns`, but Qt describes them with `QGenericMatrix<columns,rows,type>`, rows and columns are reversed. So, in @user3405291's example `myMat4x3` is actually 3x4 and equal to `[ [3 3 3 1] [1 1 2 2] [2 1 1 1] ]`. The correct solution should be declaring it as a `QGenericMatrix<3,4,float>`

Comment: @Annyo, thanks for the remark. Transposition would do as well, right?

Comment: @scopchanov No, the transpose of `myMat4x3` (as it is defined in the example) would give `[ [3 1 2] [3 1 1] [3 2 1] [1 2 1] ]`, which is still not what we want.

Comment: @Annyo, Thank you for pointing that out. I will update my answer accordingly.